# Getting an error on Nuget Pack when updating to latest Uno Platform

Tags: .net-6.0, nuget-package, uno-platform

I'm updating my library to the latest Uno version. When executing a nuget pack command, I get the following:

```
 NU1012: Some included files are included under TFMs which are missing a platform version: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios
```

When upgrading, I had to update my nuspec from:

```
 <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\monoandroid10.0\*.*" target="lib\monoandroid10.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\monoandroid11.0\*.*" target="lib\monoandroid11.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\xamarinios10\*.*" target="lib\xamarinios10" />
 </files>
```

to:

```
 <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\net6.0-android\*.*" target="lib\net6.0-android" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net6.0-ios\*.*" target="lib\net6.0-ios" />
 </files>
```

I'm assuming I need to install some new packages locally?

Comment: have you found a solution? MS developers seems to be incapable with their own answers.

Comment: I don't remember how, but I did solve this, I believe I had some missing packages I had to install from VS. I also was missing .NET 6 on my pc